# Range of a Laplace-type transform

Tags: integral-transforms, laplace-transform

I'm interested in germs of functions $f(h)$ for $h\geq 0$ small. My question is, for what functions $f(h)$ can I write, for some $\delta>0$:
$$f(h) = \frac{1}{h} \int_0^{\delta} e^{-s/h} a(s)\: ds + O(e^{-\delta/h}),\quad h\downarrow 0 \quad(1)$$
where the function $a(s)$ can be as bad as you like--e.g., $L^1$ or a measure.

**Question:** Can "every function" $f(h)$ be written in the form (1) for some $\delta>0$ and some $a(s)$? For example, "every function" could mean every smooth function. If not, can one characterize which functions can be written as in (1)?

**Comments:**

One interesting thing to note is that
$$h^k = \frac{1}{h} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-s/h} \frac{s^k}{k!} \: ds. \quad (2)$$
Because of this, any germ of an analytic function $f(h)$ can be written as in (1), just by applying (2) to the Taylor series of $f(h)$ to obtain the Taylor series for $a(s)$, and then truncating the integral so that it converges. Furthermore, (2) shows that even if $a(s)$ is real analytic, $f(h)$ need not be. In this case it is, I think, Gevrey of order $1$.

But $f(h)$ need not be analytic or even Gevrey at $h=0$; using (2) one can find an $f(h)$ with any desired Taylor series at $0$, just by prescribing the right Taylor series for $a$ at $0$.

Away from $h=0$, the integral in (1) is analytic, but the error term $O(e^{-\delta/h})$ means that $f$ need not be analytic away from $h=0$.